# How to compute Coulomb repulsion from electron density numerically

Tags: quantum-mechanics, computational-physics, density-functional-theory

The energy due to mutual repulsion of electrons (Hartree potential) is usually formulated similar to
$$U_{ee}=\frac{e^2}{2}\int\frac{n(r)n(r')}{|r-r'|}\mathrm{d^3}r~ \mathrm{d^3}r'$$

I'm not a physicist and I don't know how to interpret this integral. How can I compute it numerically?

I've tried the following:

```
tmp=0:
for j=1:length(n)
    for k=1:length(n)
           if j==i
               continue
           end                  
           tmp=tmp+((n(j)*n(k))/abs(r(j)-r(k)));
    end
end
U_ee=tmp/2;
```

However, this results in a huge electrostatic energy which is more than $10^6$ times the kinetic energy at the same temperature and pressure.
I've also heard, that $U_{ee}$ can be calculated in a different way using the Poisson equation.

Any hints?

Comment: What you've done looks right except you've forgotten to multiply by the differential element $dr\,dr^\prime$. And I assume you're working in units where $e=1$, right?

Comment: Is $n$ number density or charge density?  Perhaps you slipped up on that.

Comment: $n(r)$ is the number density.

Comment: By the way, an  important validation test is to make sure you get convergence as you increase the resolution of your grid (i.e. make $dr$ smaller).

Comment: Ok,thx. Now the kinetic energy and $U_{ee}$ are comparable, at least at higher temperatures. However, the energy due to electron-nucleus interaction $U_{en}$ is still much smaller (while U_{ee} and the kinetic energy riso to ~ $10^5$ at higher temperatures, $-U_{en}$ is not getting larger than around 300). Is that expectedly?

Comment: That doesn't sound unreasonable to me, but it depends on what system you're modelling. It's generally a good idea to validate with a system that you can model analytically (or get these numbers from an existing dft code for comparison).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about debugging code.

Comment: @ACuriousMind: No its not. The main problem was that I did not understand the integral...I've never seen that notation using r' without any comments.So I just made an assumption....but go ahead and vote for whatever you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have Maxwell's equation (I'll be using CGS, sorry for that)
$
\nabla\cdot\mathbf{E}=4\pi\rho,
$
where $E=-\nabla\phi$ (where $\phi$ is the scalar potential). Which gives us: $$\nabla^2\phi=-4\pi\rho.$$

This is the Poisson's equation and its general solution (given by the [Green's function](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Green's_function#/Table_of_Green.27s_functions)) is:
$$
\phi(\mathbf{r})=\int\frac{\rho(\mathbf{r}')}{\left|\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}'\right|}\mathrm{d}^3\mathbf{r}'.
$$

And hence the overall energy can be found as:
\begin{equation}
W=\frac{1}{2}\int\rho\phi\mathrm{d}^3\mathbf{r}.
\end{equation}

If you have a system of quasi-discrete charges, then $\rho(\mathbf{r}_i)=e\cdot n(\mathbf{r}_i)=e\cdot n_i$. If there are point charges (as far as I understood from your code), then you'll simply have a sum of $\delta$-functions, which will give you just a discrete sum (only over $\mathbf{r}_i$) like:

$$
\phi_i=\phi(\mathbf{r}_i)=\sum_{j\ne i}\frac{e\cdot n_j}{\left|\mathbf{r}_i-\mathbf{r}_j\right|},
$$

and for the energy we'll get:

$$
W=\frac{e}{2}\sum_i n_i\cdot\phi_i.
$$

So your code will look like this (in `Python`):

```
def phi(ind):
   phi0 = 0
   for j in range(NP):
      if ind != j:
         phi0 += e * n(j) / DIST(ind, j)
   return phi0
W = 0
for i in range(NP):
   W += 0.5 * e * n(i) * phi(i)
```

Comment: You forgot to keep the density in the final result. The code is about electron densities, not about discrete electron positions. With the densities, your code then boils down to the same calculation.

Comment: Well, that doesn't change much, from the point of view of calculation complexity. But, anyway, I fixed it.

Comment: Thx for your effort. I highly appreciate it. Also you're the first one who made the link to poisson's equation.

Comment: You're welcome. You can make a code twice as fast (which won't help if you got a lot of particles, but anyway) by doing $W=e\sum_{i=1}^{NP}\sum_{j=i+1}^{NP}n(i)n(j)/r_{ij}$, instead of $W=e/2\sum_{i=1}^{NP}\sum_{j=1}^{NP}n(i)n(j)/r_{ij}$. So that you don't count the relative energy $W_{ij}$ twice and then divide by $1/2$.